# Is async ever better than defer?

Tags: javascript, html

The way I understand it, scripts should be `defer`ed rather than `async`ed because that way parsing doesn't need to stop to execute them (I am going by [these graphs](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html)). If parsing has to stop, that means the page content takes longer to show up right? If that's the case, why would `async` ever be better than `defer`?

Example: I am using Google reCAPTCHA on my site. Google has asked me to insert the script just before my closing `</head>` tag:

```
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
```

Why would this script need to execute before the page finishes loading? Shouldn't I `defer` it?

Comment: However, with defer it takes longer until the script is executed, so why would that be better? In the end, as you can see in the diagrams, it takes the same combined time.

Comment: @Bergi but isn't page rendering halted while the `async` scripts are being executed?

Comment: Rendering is never halted, I guess you mean parsing. And even if it is (which isn't actually necessary), what advantage would this have? Why wouldn't having the script executed earlier be much better?

Comment: @Bergi perhaps I am misunderstanding? I think that during parsing, the page elements are being loaded and showing up on the user's screen. If parsing stops at any point, then the page elements are taking longer to show up. I am realizing now that maybe we don't actually see the content until all the parsing and javascript execution is complete. Is that correct?

Comment: No, parsing means taking the html stream and producing a document object. Rendering (and painting, i.e. showing up on the screen) happen parallel to that process and are not necessarily affected (though they typically wait for larger chunks of changes). When content shows up the first time depends on a lot of browser internals. And whether showing the content has something to do with the javascript execution depends largely on what the script does.

Comment: @Bergi so when would someone want to use `async` instead of `defer`? It still sounds to me like executing a script before parsing/rendering finishes could delay rendering a bit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135012/discussion-between-torjinx-and-bergi).

Comment: Only when the script is not aimed to be executed before the rendering, as it creates crucial page elements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alright, after scouring the internet for hours I finally have my answer! From [this fantastic blog post](https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2016/prefer-defer-over-async/):

> Scripts loaded with ASYNC are parsed and executed immediately when the resource is done downloading. Whereas DEFER scripts don’t execute until the HTML document is done being parsed (AKA, DOM Interactive or performance.timing.domInteractive).

...

> Comparing the ASYNC and DEFER waterfalls, we see that using DEFER makes DOM Interactive fire sooner and allows rendering to proceed more quickly.

HOWEVER:

> Even though ASYNC and DEFER don’t block the HTML parser, they can block rendering. This happens when they’re parsed and executed before rendering is complete and take over the browser main thread. There’s nothing in the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async) that says they have to wait until rendering is complete.

So basically, my understanding from this is that rendering (although [it happens somewhat in parallel with parsing](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#The_main_flow)) gets going faster with `defer`, but ultimately the page takes just as long to load due to all the javascripts being executed throughout the rendering process. This is slightly more satisfying for the user, since they get to see things appear sooner. However, if we really want to improve loading speed, we should [load scripts after onload](http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/why-loading-third-party-scripts-async-is-not-good-enough) where possible.

**In conclusion: There doesn't seem to be any reason to use `async` instead of `defer`.**

Comment: This answer is wrong. There is no hard and fast rule. In a situation where you have a large js file that will download slower than it takes for DomInteractive, using defer will cause the browser to wait until that script is downloaded before parsing it and issuing DomContentLoaded. If you have _other_ scripts that are waiting on this event (e.g jQuery) they will be needlessly waiting for your deferred script to download. Using async avoids this.

Comment: @calumbrodie I would love it if you could write you own answer to my original question, as I really want to understand how this works! I'm struggling to follow your explanation, probably because I don't know all the terminology because I haven't reviewed these concepts in such a long time. A lot of people have been viewing this question so a correct answer would be really helpful.

Comment: My understanding is also along the lines of calumbrodie's, although it's not as clear as I'd like it yet. I think the widespread misinterpretation has to do with the fact that there's no one-size-fits-all approach (that will always get you to FOO fastest), and also that the pretty graphs everyone uses as examples use small files & execution times as examples.

Comment: If the script is cached, it won't need to download but it still need to execute before DomContentLoaded is fired. I guess the best solution is: if you use defer, make sure ALL of your scripts rely on defer, and not on DomContentLoaded. If you can't do that (e.g. you rely on 3rd party scripts outside of your control), async is better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes async is sometimes a superior choice than defer, & sometimes an inferior one. This is easily tested by timing until the event/s you care about happen against using async or defer (or load, or inserted-by-load, etc.). Many browsers even come with built-in developer tools to show you a "*waterfall*" of timed events.

The graphs you mention are pretty and useful conceptually, but they do not present a scientific measure whatsoever. Only measuring the time to the event/s you care about will always (statistically) accurately tell you which is fastest.

You have either tested a thing, or you're relying merely on faith.

(As far as Google reCAPTCHA in particular, I don't know it intimately, but I do know that under certain implementations it attempts via various criteria available to it [like potentially even how the mouse cursor is moving before interacting with the manifested CAPTCHA] to determine ahead of time whether the page is likely being utilized by an actual human being or not. Humans certainly frequently interact with pages even before they are fully loaded, so this period would provide useful information in this regard. That said, if a script works for you no matter what your implementation, even if inferior in some way to another implementation, it works. If you don't have a method to determine successful functionality, then you will always be lost.)